# Very Slow only with setVisibility in listview (desperate)

Tags: android, listview

Thanks in advance.
I have a simple layout like this:

```
<imageview id="@+id/button1">
<imageview id="@+id/button2">
<imageview id="@+id/button3">

<listview id="@+id/list1">
<listview id="@+id/list2">
<listview id="@+id/list3">
```

Three images (buttons) and one listview for each one. I simply make VISIBLE/INVISIBLE each list when on click each button.

Each item on the lists are a little bit complex, but I use recycling, and the scrolling it´s very nice, also the load is quick but... When I change between list (repeat) only make setvisibility in each list, the process it´s very laggy.

The code of hidding list, when click button1:

```
lista1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
lista2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
lista3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Any solution? Please I´m desperate.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by very slow? its so funny

Comment: Show us the code you use to switch lists

Comment: Are the items of ur listview same ?? If so , just repopulate our listview

Comment: there is lag when change list... 1 second... I think it´s superslow.

Comment: Rachita Thanks! Very clever! :) I will try it. But... It´s strange that is more quick repopulate than hidding, no?

Comment: @Juanra use an async task to repopulate the list view .This way you can repopulate(get data to repopulate) the list view in background without blocking the UI